# Why when making a new instance to a class it's never getting to the class Init method?

Tags: c#, winforms

The project Target framework is set to .NET Framework 4.8
Build Any CPU and allow unsafe code is checked true.

In the project i have 3 directx old dll files i added as referenced.  ADD > Reference and selected the 3 dll files.

This is a link to the project : 604KB size only.

[my project link to download](https://=https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asc3SAnDqEnoaXzr9GLpe_ZMJBQ?e=zMylBz)

In form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Doppler
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Doppler dr = new Doppler();
            dr.pb1 = pictureBox1;
            dr.Init();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I used a break points on all the 3 lines in the form1 constructor and it's never getting to any of the lines. there are no errors the application is just hanging does nothing it's not even showing the form1 window when running the application.

but if for testing i put one line instead :

```
string t = "";
```

then it is getting to the line.

This is the Doppler class it's a bit long :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D;
using Microsoft.DirectX;

namespace Doppler
{
    class Doppler
    {
        [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", EntryPoint = "memset", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = false)]
        public static extern IntPtr MemSet(IntPtr dest, int c, int count);

        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
        private Stream mymem;
        private Bitmap ConvertedBmp;
        private Device D3Ddev = null;
        private PresentParameters D3Dpp = null;
        private DisplayMode DispMode;
        private Sprite D3Dsprite = null;
        private Texture backTexture = null;
        private Texture scannedCloudsTexture = null;
        private byte[] argbValuesOfTransparentTexture;
        private float distanceFromCenterPixels;
        private float distanceFromCenterKm = 200F;
        private List<Point> detectedPoints;
        private float[] angleArray, distanceArray;
        private double angleCalculation, distance;
        private Bitmap bmpnew = new Bitmap(512, 512);
        private int bytes = 2048 * 512;
        public System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pb1;

        public void Init()
        {
            timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Interval = 10;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Tick += Timer1_Tick;

            ConvertedBmp = ConvertTo24(@"D:\Downloaded Images\test.gif");
            mymem = ToStream(ConvertedBmp, ImageFormat.Bmp);

            distanceFromCenterPixels = (float)(/*183d*/ ((double)200 / 1.09289617486) * (double)distanceFromCenterKm / 200d);
            argbValuesOfTransparentTexture = new byte[bytes];

            InitializeDirectX(pb1);

            FindPoints();
            //initialize angleArray
            angleArray = new float[detectedPoints.Count];
            distanceArray = new float[detectedPoints.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < detectedPoints.Count; i++)
            {
                CalculateAngleAndDistance(detectedPoints[i].X, detectedPoints[i].Y, out angleCalculation, out distance);

                angleArray[i] = (float)angleCalculation;
                distanceArray[i] = (float)distance;
            }
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        static float angleF_ = 0.0F;
        private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (angleF_ > 360F)
            {
                angleF_ -= 360F;
            }

            ReturnTexture(scannedCloudsTexture, detectedPoints, angleArray, angleF_, bmpnew);

            DisplayOnScreen(angleF_);

            // To change direction to change += to -=
            // To change speed to raise the value 1.0d 
            angleF_ += 1.0F;
        }

        private Bitmap ConvertTo24(string inputFileName)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Bitmap bmpIn = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(inputFileName);

            Bitmap converted = new Bitmap(bmpIn.Width, bmpIn.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(converted))
            {
                // Prevent DPI conversion
                g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
                // Draw the image
                g.DrawImageUnscaled(bmpIn, 0, 0);
            }
            //converted.Save(outputFileName, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            sw.Stop();
            return converted;
        }

        public static Stream ToStream(Image image, ImageFormat formaw)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(stream, formaw);
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }

        public Boolean InitializeDirectX(System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pb1)
        {

            DispMode = Manager.Adapters[Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter].CurrentDisplayMode;
            D3Dpp = new PresentParameters();
            D3Dpp.BackBufferFormat = DispMode.Format;
            D3Dpp.PresentFlag = PresentFlag.LockableBackBuffer;

            D3Dpp.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
            D3Dpp.PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.One; //wait for vertical sync. Synchronizes the painting with
                                                              //monitor refresh rate for smoooth animation
            D3Dpp.Windowed = true; //the application has borders

            try
            {
                D3Ddev = new Device(Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter, DeviceType.Hardware, pb1.Handle,
                                                                           CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, D3Dpp);
                //D3Ddev.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.PositionColored.Format;
                D3Ddev.RenderState.Lighting = false;
                D3Ddev.RenderState.CullMode = Cull.CounterClockwise;

                //load imagesBmp to panelTexture
                //panelTexture = Texture.FromBitmap(D3Ddev, imagesBmp, Usage.Dynamic, Pool.Default)

                backTexture = TextureLoader.FromStream(D3Ddev, mymem);




                //scannerTexture = TextureLoader.FromFile(D3Ddev, @"D:\Buttons\Radar\radar.png");
                scannedCloudsTexture = new Texture(D3Ddev, 512, 512, 1, Usage.Dynamic, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Default);

                //sprite is used to draw the texture
                D3Dsprite = new Sprite(D3Ddev);

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        Bitmap bmpn;
        float angle = 0;
        private void DisplayOnScreen(float angleF)
        {

            if (angle < 360)
            {
                bmpn = new Bitmap(512, 512);
                angle++;
            }
            else
            {
                angle = 361;
            }
            Surface backbuffer;
            Brush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(110, 0, 255, 0)); //semi transparent color to draw the rotating cone 
            Graphics g;

            //clear the backbuffer with Color.FromArgb(56, 56, 56). This is the double buffer mechanism. Drawing to offscreen 
            //backbuffer and in the end flipping it to main one which is our panelContainer 
            D3Ddev.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, Color.FromArgb(56, 56, 56), 1, 0);
            D3Ddev.BeginScene();

            //Draw Sprites 
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
            D3Dsprite.Begin(SpriteFlags.AlphaBlend);

            // bitmap with clouds 
            D3Dsprite.Draw2D(backTexture, new PointF(0, 0), 0F, new PointF(0F, 0F), Color.White);
            //the part of clouds that are inside the cone 
            D3Dsprite.Draw2D(scannedCloudsTexture, new PointF(0F, 0F), 0F, new PointF(0F, 0F), Color.White);
            //rotate cone 
            //D3Dsprite.Draw2D(scannerTexture, new PointF(104.5F, 0F), angle, new PointF(256F, 255F), Color.White); 

            D3Dsprite.Flush();
            D3Dsprite.End();
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 


            //Draw the cone. 
            using (backbuffer = D3Ddev.GetBackBuffer(0, 0, BackBufferType.Mono))
            {
                using (g = backbuffer.GetGraphics())
                {
                    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                    g.FillPie(myBrush, 256F - distanceFromCenterPixels, 255F - distanceFromCenterPixels,
                    distanceFromCenterPixels * 2F, distanceFromCenterPixels * 2F, angleF - 23F, 46F);
                    if (angle <= 360)
                    {

                    }

                }
            }

            D3Ddev.EndScene();
            D3Ddev.Present(); //performs the flipping 

        }

        private void CalculateAngleAndDistance(int x, int y, out double angle, out double distance)
        {
            Double dbl = -1.0d;
            Point center = new Point(256, 255);

            distance = Math.Sqrt((double)((center.Y - y) * (center.Y - y) + (center.X - x) * (center.X - x)));

            if (y == center.Y && x > center.X)
            {
                dbl = 0d;
                angle = dbl;

                return;
            }
            else if (x == center.X && y > center.Y)
            {
                dbl = 90d;
                angle = dbl;

                return;
            }
            else if (y == center.Y && x < center.X)
            {
                dbl = 180d;
                angle = dbl;

                return;
            }
            else if (x == center.X && y < center.Y)
            {
                dbl = 279d;
                angle = dbl;

                return;
            }
            else if (x == center.X && y == center.Y)
            {
                angle = dbl;

                return;
            }

            if (x > center.X && y > center.Y) //1
            {
                dbl = Math.Atan(((double)y - (double)center.Y) / ((double)x - (double)center.X));
                dbl = 180d * dbl / Math.PI;
            }
            else if (x < center.X && y > center.Y) //2
            {
                dbl = Math.Atan(((double)y - (double)center.Y) / ((double)center.X - (double)x));
                dbl = 180d * dbl / Math.PI;
                dbl = 180d - dbl;
            }
            else if (x < center.X && y < center.Y) //3
            {
                dbl = Math.Atan(((double)center.Y - (double)y) / ((double)center.X - (double)x));
                dbl = 180d * dbl / Math.PI;
                dbl += 180d;
            }
            else //4
            {
                dbl = Math.Atan(((double)center.Y - (double)y) / ((double)x - (double)center.X));
                dbl = 180d * dbl / Math.PI;
                dbl = 360d - dbl;
            }


            angle = dbl;
        }

        private void ReturnTexture(Texture texture_take, List<Point> lstPnt, float[] anglArr, float angle, Bitmap bmpNew)
        {
            int i, j, stride = 2048;
            float angleBefore, angleAfter;
            GraphicsStream textureStream;
            Boolean bl = false;

            if (bmpNew.Width != 512 && bmpNew.Height != 512)
                throw new Exception("Bitmaps must be of same size.");

            //sets texture to complete transparent 
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (byte* p = argbValuesOfTransparentTexture)
                {
                    MemSet((IntPtr)p, 0x0, argbValuesOfTransparentTexture.Length);
                }
            }


            angleAfter = angle + 23F;

            if (angleAfter >= 360F)
            {
                angleAfter -= 360F;
            }

            angleBefore = angleAfter - 46;

            if (angleBefore < 0F)
            {
                angleBefore += 360F;
                bl = true;
            }

            BitmapData bmD = bmpNew.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpNew.Width, bmpNew.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            unsafe
            {
                byte* p = (byte*)bmD.Scan0.ToPointer();
                //checks all points and draws yellow only those who are inside the cone 
                for (i = 0; i < lstPnt.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (anglArr[i] == -1F)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (bl == true)
                    {
                        if (anglArr[i] <= angleAfter || anglArr[i] >= angleBefore) //if point angle is inside cone. Cone angle is 46 degrees 
                        {
                            if (distanceArray[i] <= distanceFromCenterPixels)
                            {
                                j = lstPnt[i].Y * stride + lstPnt[i].X * 4;

                                //yellow 
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 0] = (byte)0;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 1] = (byte)255;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 2] = (byte)255;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 3] = (byte)255;

                                p[j] = (byte)0;
                                p[j + 1] = (byte)0;
                                p[j + 2] = (byte)255;
                                p[j + 3] = (byte)255;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (anglArr[i] <= angleAfter && anglArr[i] >= angleBefore) //if point angle is inside cone. Cone angle is 46 degrees 
                        {
                            if (distanceArray[i] <= distanceFromCenterPixels)
                            {
                                j = lstPnt[i].Y * stride + lstPnt[i].X * 4;

                                //yellow 
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 0] = (byte)0;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 1] = (byte)255;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 2] = (byte)255;
                                argbValuesOfTransparentTexture[j + 3] = (byte)255;

                                p[j] = (byte)0;
                                p[j + 1] = (byte)0;
                                p[j + 2] = (byte)255;
                                p[j + 3] = (byte)255;
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            //if (angle <= 360)
            //  pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"c:\coneimages\" + angle + ".gif");

            bmpNew.UnlockBits(bmD);



            {
                using (textureStream = texture_take.LockRectangle(0, LockFlags.None))
                {
                    textureStream.Write(argbValuesOfTransparentTexture);
                    texture_take.UnlockRectangle(0);
                }

                //if (angle <= 360)
                //  pictureBox1.Image.Save(@"c:\coneimages\" + angle + ".gif");
            }
        }

        private void FindPoints()
        {


            //Bitmap bmptest;
            GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
            int x, y, p, j, wdthHght;
            int bytes;
            //byte error_ = 5;
            byte[] rgbValuesWithClouds;
            byte[] rgbValuesWithoutClouds;
            IntPtr ptr;
            Rectangle rect;
            BitmapData bitmap_Data;

            Bitmap bmpWithClouds; //No memory is allocated
            Bitmap bmpWithoutClouds; //No memory is allocated

            gp.AddEllipse(new RectangleF(73, 72, 367, 367));

            //gp.CloseFigure();

            //using the using statement, bmpWithClouds bitmap is automatically disposed at the end of statement. No memory leaks :)
            using (bmpWithClouds = new Bitmap(mymem))//@"D:\MyWeatherStation-Images-And-Icons\radartobmp.bmp")) //24 bit bitmap
            {
                rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpWithClouds.Width, bmpWithClouds.Height);
                wdthHght = bmpWithClouds.Width;

                //Lock bitmap to copy its color information fast
                bitmap_Data = bmpWithClouds.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmpWithClouds.PixelFormat);
                ptr = bitmap_Data.Scan0;
                bytes = bitmap_Data.Stride * bmpWithClouds.Height;

                rgbValuesWithClouds = new byte[bytes];

                //copy color information to rgbValues array
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValuesWithClouds, 0, bytes);
                //we are done copying so unlock bitmap. We dont need it anymore
                bmpWithClouds.UnlockBits(bitmap_Data);
            }


            //using the using statement, bmpWithClouds bitmap is automatically disposed at the end of statement. No memory leaks :)
            using (bmpWithoutClouds = new Bitmap(
                @"D:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\bin\x86\Release\WithoutClouds.bmp"))//su + "\\WithoutClouds.bmp")) //24 bit bitmap
            {
                rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpWithoutClouds.Width, bmpWithoutClouds.Height);

                //Lock bitmap to copy its color information fast
                bitmap_Data = bmpWithoutClouds.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmpWithoutClouds.PixelFormat);
                ptr = bitmap_Data.Scan0;
                bytes = bitmap_Data.Stride * bmpWithoutClouds.Height;

                rgbValuesWithoutClouds = new byte[bytes];

                //copy color information to rgbValues array
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValuesWithoutClouds, 0, bytes);
                //we are done copying so unlock bitmap. We dont need it anymore
                bmpWithoutClouds.UnlockBits(bitmap_Data);
            }

            // Each position in these arrays, rgbValuesWithoutClouds and rgbValuesWithClouds, corresponds a color. eg
            // First pixel   Second pixel   Third pixel   Forth pixel .... // bitmaps
            //    B G R          B G R         B G R         B G R    .... // rgbValues arrays
            //bmptest = new Bitmap(512, 512);
            detectedPoints = new List<Point>();

            for (y = 0; y < wdthHght; y++)
            {
                j = 0;
                for (x = 0; x < wdthHght; x++)
                {

                    p = y * wdthHght * 3 + j;

                    if (rgbValuesWithClouds[p] != rgbValuesWithoutClouds[p])
                    {
                        detectedPoints.Add(new Point(x, y));
                        //bmptest.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
                    }

                    j += 3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you put the line `string t = "";`? Did you put it before the three lines of code that aren;t getting hit? If so, what happens if you put a breakpoint on the `string` line and then step through? Does it execute the next three lines?

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, I thnk you should move those lines to `Form1_Load`, as that is where you are supposed to put this sort of thing. Not sure if there is any harm in doing this sort of thing in a form constructor, but from what I remember of WinForms (been a fw years), we always used the `Form_Load` event

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel nothing worked. i thinkg it's something with this old dll directox files i added as reference to the project.  not sure 100%.

Comment: Try a new project, and check that the `Form1_Load` event is called. If so, add the DLLs, and check again. If it's still being called, then add those three lines in and see what happens